# Jgitflow plugin not creating git tags

Tags: maven, jenkins, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I have the following jgitflow plugin and use Jenkins to perform automated releases. Using the command `mvn --batch-mode  jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish`. Everything is working however, I never see any tags in github. As per the docs unless notags is used all my releases should create tags. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-m4.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <flowInitContext>
            <masterBranchName>release</masterBranchName>
            <developBranchName>master</developBranchName>
            <releaseBranchPrefix>release-</releaseBranchPrefix>
            <versionTagPrefix>release-</versionTagPrefix>
        </flowInitContext>
        <noReleaseMerge>true</noReleaseMerge>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Using release-start and finish separately did not help either. See below:

```
mvn --batch-mode  jgitflow:release-start -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests
git push --tags
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out eventually that the `versionTagPrefix` cannot be the same as the `releaseBranchPrefix` otherwise the tagging silently fails.

Answer (score 2):

All changes are made local. You need to push them to remote:

- develop
- Tag (git push --tag)
- master

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, it's creating a local tag only, so you need to push it, something like `git push --tags`

Comment: ```git tag -l``` shows nothing so it does not seem to be creating local tags either if I understand this command correctly.

Comment: how did you do that?  ```1) mvn jgitflow:release-start 2) git push --tags 3) mvn jgitflow:release-finish``` working as clocks

Comment: ah, I was doing 1), 3), 2) let me test in that order.

Comment: Does not seem to help. Still no tags. See updated question

Comment: Hm, if your master branch is called "release" (it seems like, from your config), then probably you should push to `origin/release` ?